# Finding which polygons lie along a polyline in ArcMap 10.4

Tags: arcmap, polygon, line

I work in ArcMap 10.4.

I'm looking for a tool/function which would return a list of polygons through which a polyline goes. To be more specific - I have a polygon layer of administrative units and polyline features (gaspipes etc). I made a simple sketch of what I mean (see pic below).
Is there a way to return the list of "touched" polygons the polyline "goes" through?

[image]

Comment: Intersect, open attr table of output. Or spatial join

Comment: Select by location tool in the standard toolbar in ArcMap will do that, it is usually 6 buttons to the right of the pan tool (the little hand)...

Comment: Yes, I used the Intersect tool. Is there a way to make the Intersect tool work in Web App Builder in ArcGIS Online? What I wanted to do is to let users to add their own polyline to the existing web map, run the "intersect" tool so they would get the list of "touched" polygons.

Comment: Your question is about ArcMap not "Web App Builder in ArcGIS Online"! That is a completely different environment. If you want a solution about that you need to write another question or heavily modify this question.

Answer (score 1):

these are several choices. I'm using Pro, but It should be quite the same process as ArcMap.

1. **Select by location -> right click your layer, data, export to feature**.
2. or **make this kind of model using a model builder**, and make your
   input    as parameters. the output should be polygons that you
   previously    selected [image: model builder]
3. select by location, right-click your layer, and click **make a new
   layer from the selected feature** [image: (create new layer from selected feature)]